# How can UI elements in iOS be updated from a loop without threads?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I want to update a label from a loop, for example like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    int i=0; 
    while (1) {
         i++;
         [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.05];  // do some computation,
         [myLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]]; // show the result!
         [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
    }

  }
```

Assume that instead of sleep some heavy computation is done.
I do not want the overhead of doing the computation in the background.
The Windows equivalent for handling this problem would be .DoEvents, as this example shows:
http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1305106&page=1

Is there a similar solution for this in iOS?

[self.view setNeedsDisplay] does not work at all!

There must be some way to process application events from iOS on a controlled schedule in the main thread... Like .DoEvents in windows, despite all its shortcomings is quite useful for some simple applications.

I guess this is like a game-loop but with UI components.

Comment: try using  performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:  
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:inModes:

Comment: [self.view performSelector:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil afterDelay:0]; doesn't work...

Comment: [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(heavyDutyComputation) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES]; doesn't work...

Answer (score 3):

The way you would do this is as follows:

```
-(void) incrementCounter:(NSNumber *)i {             
    [myLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [i intValue]]]; // show the result!
    [self performSelector:@selector(incrementCounter:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i.intValue+1] afterDelay:0.05];    
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // start the loop
    [self incrementCounter:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
}
```

The basic idea here is to increment the counter after a slight delay 0.05 to give the main UI thread a chance to flush all UI events, which makes up for explicitly calling .DoEvents in the Windows world.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to implement a counter using a label? You can use NSTimer to call a method that updates your counter every X milliseconds, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSTimer` in `iOS` if you want to update UI components.

```
NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 60.0 target: self
                                   selector: @selector(callAfterSomeSecond:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
```

Implement the callAfterSomeSecond: as below :

```
-(void) callAfterSomeSecond:(NSTimer*) timer 
{
   static int counter = 0;

   if(counter == 100)
   {
      [timer invalidate];
   }
   [myLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counter ]];
   [self.view layoutSubviews];
   counter++;
}
```

Comment: Timers are no option (because the loop may never exit and we want to modify the user interface within that loop). And I don't think that a timer would work if the main thread is blocked.

Comment: @brbr  : it will be exited when `counter` become 100 . see I'm invalidating `NSTimer` at 100 .

Answer (score 0):

in your code, the while loop runs in the Main thread, and the UI update also should be done in Main thread, so while the loop is running, the Main thread is kind of 'blocked'(busy), so UI update cannot be performed.

I think what I want to say is not what you want. to resolve it, you have to put the heavy computing in another thread, using NSOperation or GCD for example.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to do your computation on a different thread, but when that's not feasible, you can wrap the code that affects the UI in a CATransaction. In my tests this will update the UI immediately rather than needing to wait till the next run loop.

```
while (1) {
 [CATransaction begin];
 //Your UI code here
 [CATransaction commit];
}
```